# use fabric8 kubernetes java lient delete resource with delete option not work

Tags: fabric8, fabric8-kubernetes-client

```
    Boolean delete = apiClient.apps().statefulSets().inNamespace(namespace).withName(name)
            .withPropagationPolicy(DeletionPropagation.ORPHAN)
            .delete();
    if (delete != null && delete) {
        log.info("Delete sts {}/{}", namespace, name);
    }
```

Although I have set propagationpolicy to orphan, the dependency pod was deleted after statefulset deletion which expect pod not to be deleted.
Append:
Api version I used is 5.10.1
kubernetes version is 1.19

Comment: That's quite old version of Kubernetes Client. Is it possible to upgrade Kubernetes Client to latest versions?

Comment: @RohanKumar It turn out a problem of the mongodb operator. Thanks for your reply.